# MVC display dynamically created image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC 5 with VS2015.

I am trying to display a dynamically generated image file in a folder. Example:

```
<img alt="Test.png" src="http://localhost:52853/Content/Download/Bin/1-30611/Test.png"/>
```

Where *Content/Download* folders are pre-created. But the *Bin/1-30611* folders and the *Test.png* are created dynamically during runtime.

Unfortunately MVC kept on complaining that the resource is not found.

Since we all know that MVC URL resources are not linked to their location in the physical folder (except ~/content, or is my assumption wrong?), may I know what I might have missed?

Hope someone can shed some light on this.

And no, I can't put all my images in the ~/Content folder, because there are just too many of them, and they need to be cleaned/removed automatically from time to time.

Or must I create a special controller action to return the image file?

Comment: If the sub folders are being created dynamically, then it makes no sense to be hard coding the path. You could use a view model property (or `ViewBag` property) containing the path and then use `src="@Model.ImagePath"`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the above path is just for illustrating purposes only. In fact the entire path (including the img element) is created dynamically.

Comment: So what is you problem then? You need to show the relevant code.

Comment: My problem is, I have an image file generated dynamically at : Content/Download/Bin/1-30611/Test.png. but it cannot be displayed using the <img> tag.

Comment: So you have said, but you have not shown how you are creating the `<img>` tag

Comment: As I said it is not important. But if you insist, here it is. @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.MapFile))
   {
    <img src="@Model.MapFile" alt="@Model.UIMap.Description" />
   }

Comment: can you append datetime variable in the end of image to avoid a\caching issue and other thing to try is different folder and also check for permission for that folder

Comment: Of course it matters, and it will work fine if the value of `MapFile` is correct - `<img src= "@Url.Content(Model.MapFile)" alt="Image" />` where `MapFile` is `~/Content/Download/Bin/1-30611/Test.png`

Comment: Thanks for the try, but it doesn't. I am trying to create a controller action to return the file result instead.

Comment: It does for me and everyone else :)

Comment: have you try like this <img src= '@Url.Content("~/" +Model.MapFile)' alt="Image" /> ?

Comment: Model.MapFile in this path starts with Content/Download.. right?